# How to pass BroadcastReceiver content to an Activity within same Java class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

i working on a custom dailer. So far i am able make the user select the dailer he wants to use but when he chooses my dailer the number he wants to call is not dailed; instead my activity is shown.

I want it to show make the call based on the selected number and show my activity.

```
public class myActivity extends TabsActivity {

private OneActivity bb;
private String oldNumber2;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    class OneActivity extends BroadcastReceiver { 

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                                 
            final String Number1 = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); 
            Toast.makeText(context, Number1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + Number1));
            launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(dial);
        }
     }
```

When i checked the log, i found that the phone number is loaded into the BoradcastReceiver but not dailed out. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + Number1));
dial.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(dial);
```

Add the following to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But it still doesnt fire the dial Intent.

Comment: Try making a seperate class which extends broadcast receiver instead of having it as a inner class in onCreate()

Answer (score -1):

you can use setter/getter methods for such purpose.

see this example, first create a separate class file

```
public class passData
{
     private String number; 

     public void setNumber ( String number )
     {
         this.number = number;
     }

     public String getNumber ()
     {
         return number;
     }
}
```

Now you need to set your Number1 variable in to this class's method using set method, and you can get its value in to any other class or in activity, from whole project.

Comment: @ Lucifer, could you please elaborate more with regards to BroadcastReceiver.class. Thank you

Comment: sure, what do you want to know, tell me.

Comment: Ok, as you can see from my code. OneActivity extends BroadcastReceiver which onReceive i get the dailed value but it doesn't dail it out. Although, i have made my corrections as user906 suggested.But it still doesn't work

Comment: where is your dialing code?  please upate your question with dialing code.

Comment: The dialing code is: final String Number1 = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

Comment: why you are dialing it in BroadcastReceiver, you can do it in activity code.

Comment: please, help with suggestions on how to do it in an activity.

Comment: well I have never done dialing code. let see, I will  check it tomorrow, it is night here in india. so now I am going to sleep. talk with you tomorrow